# Add letters after wilcox.test

Tags: r, boxplot

[image]
From a dataframe (myData) like the one below, I've performed
`pairwise.wilcox.test(myData$Number of sp,myData$Samples,p.adjust.method="BH")` and I have something like this
[image]

I want to perform a boxplot using the same data, but with letters in each box to mark significant differences among samples. I'm really new to statistics, and I'm sorry for the question, but how can I achieve the plot that I need?

Comment: Hi Cyndi, I noticed you only have 3 values per sample, is that correct? So if you make a wilcoxon test , or a boxplot, it really doesn't make much sense. Because wilcoxon test is ranked based, and with 3 values.. testing significance of ranking doesn't make sense. Likewise for boxplot, you plot median interquantile range etc, and you have only 3 values..

Comment: yes, that's true. Now I see, thank you very much.